# SubSonic 3 / ActiveRecord: Find() on non-primary key field failing (VB.NET only)

Tags: vb.net, subsonic, subsonic3

I'm getting an SqlException when I call Find() on a non-primary key field.  I only experience this when I make this call in VB.

Details:

- SubSonic 3.0.0.3 and ActiveRecord
- Visual Studio 2008 solution

  - SubSonic and T4 templates in a C# class library project
  - My VB application in a separate project referencing the SubSonic project

In my VB application, I am trying to call Find() on one of the SubSonic generated classes, like so:

```
dim foo = Orders.Find(Function(myOrder as Order) myOrder.CustomerID = 1)
```

This is failing in ActiveRecord.cs, in this method from the (generated) Order class at:

```
public static IList<Order> Find(Expression<Func<Order, bool>> expression) {
    var repo = GetRepo();
    return repo.Find(expression).ToList();   '<---- exception here
}
```

with the following exception

```
    SqlException was unhandled by user code
    Incorrect syntax near 'LESS_THAN_SIGN'
```

(Replace the `LESS_THAN_SIGN` with a less than sign; can't figure out the escaping in stackoverflow)

I don't have a problem when I call Find with a function that references the primary key, such as:

```
dim foo = Orders.Find(Function(myOrder as Order) myOrder.OrderID = 1)
```

I also don't have a problem when I do this in C#.

What am I doing wrong?  Is this related to ["VB.net can’t find by string"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1145829/vb-net-cant-find-by-string) ?

Comment: Has this been raised as an issue on github?  I'll have a wee nosey at the problem.  I gather that CustomerID and OrderID are integers.

Comment: An answer (and my comment to go with it) was deleted.  I did a little more work and root caused it to this:

When I call Find() on a column that allows nulls, SubSonic is generating incorrect SQL. This happens only when I call Find() from a VB.NET project (SubSonic + templates are in a separate C# project in the same solution). If I call Find() from a C# project, there is no problem.

I reported it on github as http://github.com/subsonic/SubSonic-3.0/issues#issue/102

Comment: Oh dear... The problem is the expression tree created.
The basically myOrder.CustomerID = 1 becomes...
  p => Convert((p.CategoryID = ConvertChecked(4)))
Where in C# the same expression becomes...
  p => (p.CategoryID = Convert(4))